# I can´t simulate HTML form post with HttpClientMultipartFormDataContent

Tags: c#, vb.net, httpclient

When submit this HTML in web browser:

```
<form method="post" action="https://cot.arba.gov.ar/TransporteBienes/SeguridadCliente/presentarRemitos.do">
    <input type="text" name="user" value="x"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I receive this result (spected result beacause I not send password parameter):

```
<TBError>
   <tipoError>DATO</tipoError>
   <codigoError>08</codigoError>
   <mensajeError>Error de parámetro: Parámetro requerido: password</mensajeError>
</TBError>
```

But... when I submit using .NET framework with this code:

```
Using httpClient As New HttpClient
   Dim Form As New MultipartFormDataContent
   Form.Add(New StringContent("x"), "user")
   Dim response = Await httpClient.PostAsync("https://cot.arba.gov.ar/TransporteBienes/SeguridadCliente/presentarRemitos.do", Form)
   Dim sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
   MessageBox.Show(sd)
End Using
```

I receive this result (NOT spected result and different of first sample):

```
<TBError>
   <tipoError>DATO</tipoError>
   <codigoError>87</codigoError>
   <mensajeError>El formulario multipart enviado es incorrecto. Verifique las especifiaciones para la aplicaci�n cliente.</mensajeError>
</TBError>
```

The question is: How can I get same result of html sample using .NET framework?

Thanks

Comment: To post a WebForm with HttpClient/WebRequest you have to pass all parts that compose the Form data, which includes all `INPUT` elements, visible or not visible, plus the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` value pairs, if present. Be sure you can accept cookies. Also, the server may redirect you to the same login page the first time you connect, so be also ready to handle a 301/302 redirection, just in case.

Comment: The redirection can also be a 200 (`OK`) but with the `Location` header set. This can be handled setting `AllowAutoRedirect = true`.

Comment: CLARIFICATION: Once this works, I have to add the password param and upload a file, all in same post.